# BigQuery: How to sum rows that share a similar term together

Tags: google-bigquery

i have the following table and im looking to create a query that will have 3 equations

- sum "like%" and "%love%" count values together and call that Top 2 Box
- sum the count of "dislike%" and "%hate%" as Bottom 2 Box
- sum count of "%neutral%" together

for some reason my query is producing null and also placing the 3 values i want as their own individual columns when I want these 3 values to be in rows.

**test 2 campaign table**

| values | count |
| --- | --- |
| like | 5 |
| like it | 5 |
| love | 5 |
| loveit | 5 |
| hate | 1 |
| hate it | 0 |
| dislike it | 3 |
| neutral | 10 |

WIP (work in progress) query

```sql
SELECT
  sum (CASE
      WHEN VALUES ="%love%" OR VALUES ="like%" THEN count
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS Top2,
  sum (CASE
      WHEN VALUES ="%hate%" OR VALUES ="dislike%" THEN count
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS Bottom2,
  sum (CASE
      WHEN VALUES ="%neutral%" THEN count
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS Neutral
FROM
  `test 2 campaign rating`
```

**output from query**

| Top2 | Bottom2 | Neutral |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |

Top2 Bottom2 Neutral
null null null

**desired output**

| values | count |
| --- | --- |
| Top2 | 20 |
| Bottom2 | 4 |
| Neutral | 10 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below query.

```sql
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN values LIKE "%love%" OR values LIKE "like%" THEN 'Top2'
         WHEN values LIKE "%hate%" OR values LIKE "dislike%" THEN 'Bottom2'
         ELSE 'Neutral'
       END AS values,
       SUM(count) AS count
  FROM campaign_table 
 GROUP BY values;
```

**Query results**

[image]